# How to store user info after login in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I am trying to make an api call in login and I want to store it in Vuex store. So in the beginning my mutation:

```
export const STORE_USER = (state, {user}) => {
    state.user = user;
}
```

and my action:

```
export const storeUser = ({commit}, {user}) => {
    commit('STORE_USER', {user});
}
```

So as you see after login, I want to make an api call and get the user information. I want to this user information in Vuex store but it comes empty.

[image]

So I am expecting the state that you see above should be filled after login. My login component is:

```
export default {
    name: 'Login',
    mounted() {
        EventBus.$on(GENERAL_APP_CONSTANTS.Events.CheckAuthentication, () => {
            this.authenticated = authHelper.validAuthentication();
            this.cookie = cookieHelper.getCookie(this.cookieName);
            this.cookieValue = cookieHelper.getCookieValue(this.cookie);
            if (this.authenticated) {
                this.email = this.password = "";
                this.authenticationFailed = false;
                this.storeUser();
            }
        });
        EventBus.$on(GENERAL_APP_CONSTANTS.Events.LoginFailed, () => {
            this.authenticationFailed = true
        });
    },
    data () {
        return {
            authenticated: false,
            authenticationFailed: false,
            email: '',
            password: '',
            rememberMe: false,
            cookieName: "_token",
            cookie: "",
            cookieValue: "",
        }
    },
    methods: {
        signIn: function () {
            authHelper.signIn(this.email, this.password, () => {
                this.$router.push({name: 'home'});
            });
        },
        storeUser: function () {
            apiHelper.getRequest(
                `/users/${cookieHelper.parseJwt(this.cookieValue).user_id}`,
                (response) => {
                    this.$store.dispatch('storeUser', {
                        user: response.data,
                    })
                }
            )
        },
    }
}
```

So why do you think the in-store user Object is empty? Because I response.data is not empty either. Please let me know.

Comment: How are your action and mutation added to the Vuex store instance? If you add `console.log` messages in the action and mutation, do you see them being logged?

Comment: It seems everything is okay. Would you log `response.data`?

Comment: this is my store: export default {
    user: {
    },
    token: null,
    cart: {
        "attributes": {
            "items": [],
        }
    },
    cart_token: null,
}

Comment: I might do something wrong here also